# windows kernel driver and undocumented API

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I try to use an undocumented API while developing a windows kernel driver. Please don't tell me this is not the best thing to do ;)

Anyway, the undocumented API is **PsGetProcessPeb** that i found with IDA into ntoskrnl.exe

I define the following structures:

- _PEB
- _PEB_LDR_DATA
- _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY

Also, I found that I have to define the function like:

```
NTKERNELAPI PPEB NTAPI PsGetProcessPeb(IN PEPROCESS Process);
```

The code (a part of) that I try to compile is:

```
PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ProcessId, &pProcess);
PPEB pPeb = PsGetProcessPeb(pProcess);
```

When i try to compile I get the following error code:

- LNK2019
- LNK1120: unresolved externals

The externals that is not resolved is **PsGetProcessPeb**

I guess that the linker doesn't find the function and doesn't know how to link.

The OS used to compile is Windows 10 build 19044 (x64) and I use Visual Studio 2019.

If you have any idea, please let me know.

Regards

Comment: This is no different than usermode, if you want to call the function directly you need a import library (.lib). The other option is to find the function at run time...

Comment: thanks for your reply. Do you have an example to show me how to link PsGetProcessPeb ?

Comment: Make your own .lib if you can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

The key to use an undocumented API is to find the API's address.

In kernelland, there is MmGetSystemRoutineAddress().

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-mmgetsystemroutineaddress

The `MmGetSystemRoutineAddress` routine returns a pointer to a function specified by `SystemRoutineName`.

**Syntax**

C++

```
PVOID MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(
  [in] PUNICODE_STRING SystemRoutineName
);
```

**Parameters**

```
[in] SystemRoutineName
```

Specifies the name of the system routine to resolve.

**Return value**

If the function name can be resolved, the routine returns a pointer to the function. Otherwise, the routine returns NULL.

**Remarks**

Drivers can use this routine to determine if a routine is available on a specific version of Windows. It can only be used for routines exported by the kernel or HAL, not for any driver-defined routine.